# How can I create a newline in a rich textbox for C#?

Tags: c#

I am making an application that displays some useful tags for HTML. The problem is, I want to make each tag and use have its own line. However, nothing seems to be working. I have tried Environment.Newline and I have also tried \n\n but neither of those do anything. I've looked everywhere for an answer but I haven't gotten any. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: AppendText is a method not a property use as shown in this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/52b33a9a-1f7a-41f2-be92-b726970d315f/how-to-insert-a-new-line-programmatically-in-a-richtextbox-control?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

```
myRichTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + "My new line.";

// Or

myRichTextBox.AppendText( Environment.NewLine + "My new line." );
```

I saw the answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/52b33a9a-1f7a-41f2-be92-b726970d315f/how-to-insert-a-new-line-programmatically-in-a-richtextbox-control?forum=csharpgeneral), and it goes into more discussion.